# Executing Visual Basic on an existing website

Tags: internet-explorer

I am trying to figure out how to manipulate form fields (text boxes and buttons) on a webpage that is already open, without having to open a new instance of Internet Explorer and without having to navigate to a particular URL first.

I currently have the following code that opens google, fills in the search field, and clicks the Google Search button:

```
    Sub Main

    Dim objIE
    Dim UserN
    Dim url As String


    url = "http://www.google.com"


    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate url

    WaitForLoad (objIE)
    ' runs the sub "Wait for Load" that waits until the page is fully loaded before continuing the script
    MsgBox "It Loaded"
    Set UserN = objIE.document.getElementsByName("q")
    If Not UserN Is Nothing Then
' fill in first element named "q", assumed to be the login name field
        UserN(0).value = "Dragon NaturallySpeaking"
    End If
    Wait 2
    Dim f
    Set f = objIE.document.getElementsByName("btnK")
    f(0).click
    End Sub
    Sub WaitForLoad (objIE)
      Do While objIE.Busy
        Wait .1
      Loop
    End Sub
```

My current problem is that I want to be able to fill in the search field and click on the Google Search button WITHOUT having to navigate to www.google.com first. For example, I have already opened my browser and gone to www.google.com, but now I want to execute the script that fills out the text field and clicks the button. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to do this. Ive tried using Set objIE = GetObject("InternetExplorer.Application") - instead of CreateObject - and removing objIE.Visible=True and ObjIE.Navigate url, but this only returns an error.